# Installing package with pip doesn't appear in pip list

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm having issues installing any python package into my pipenv on macOS 10.14.4. I've been using a pipenv with openCV for some time now, but I need sklearn and pandas. I can install them with pip, which succeeds. But when I then try `pip list`, the packages don't appear.

I've tried installing it in two ways, the first one how I always do it:

```
(assignments-0VzU3jlg) ~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/43/fd867e3347559845c8f993059d410c50a1e18709f1c4d4b3b47323a06a37/pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /Users/pieterdelobelle/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.2)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.24.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 six-1.12.0
```

But it's not in `pip list`, and the import in python also fails.

```
(assignments-0VzU3jlg) ~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ pip list
Package       Version 
------------- --------
numpy         1.16.2  
opencv-python 4.0.0.21
pip           19.0.3  
setuptools    40.8.0  
wheel         0.33.1
```

Now, since that $PATH might be messed up, I've tried calling that pip directly, as shown below. But the issue is still exactly the same.

```
 ~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ /Users/pieter/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/bin/pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/43/fd867e3347559845c8f993059d410c50a1e18709f1c4d4b3b47323a06a37/pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /Users/pieterdelobelle/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.2)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, six, python-dateutil, pandas
Successfully installed pandas-0.24.2 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2018.9 six-1.12.0
```

```
~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ /Users/pieter/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/bin/pip list
Package       Version 
------------- --------
numpy         1.16.2  
opencv-python 4.0.0.21
pip           19.0.3  
setuptools    40.8.0  
wheel         0.33.1
```

Now, I've had some issues installing openCV correctly in the virtualenv, so I might have done something to mess this up. But I don't understand how this—and especially the second try—can't correctly install the packages...

For reference, I'm using `pip 19.0.3`:

```
~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ /Users/pieter/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/bin/pip --version 
pip 19.0.3 from /Users/pieter/.local/share/virtualenvs/assignments-0VzU3jlg/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

**edit**
I'm using pipenv. The `pipenv install pandas` command adds pandas to the pipfile, but doesn't allow me to use it, not even in a shell (`pipenv shell`) afterwards.

```
 ~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ pipenv install pandas
Installing pandas…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (caa119)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 12/12 — 00:00:08
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

```
 ~/Doc/2018/A/com/a $ pipenv run python -c "import pandas as pd"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: Have you tried `pipenv install pandas`?

Comment: @Merig I jus tried it. It adds pandas to the pipfile and the lock, but it's still not available. I've updated my question with the results